# Next-optimized-images: Error Module parse failed, Unexpected character ''"

Tags: performance, frontend, next.js, webpack-4

I'm trying to optimize my nextjs page images with next-optimized-images

This is the next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
...
  withOptimizedImages: withOptimizedImages({
    webpack(config) {
      config.resolve.alias.images = path.join(__dirname, 'public')
      return config
    }
  }),
...
```

Here is how I import image to components:

```
require(`public/assets/icons/${iconName}`)
```

My Error:

```
./public/assets/icons/website/information/hiring-black.svg 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

I'm using latest version of next-optimized-image and tried different guides but still no luck.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Next.js now optimize images by default.
Refer: [next/image](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image)

If you need svg, you need to try adding [svgr-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@svgr/webpack) loader.

Install: `yarn add @svgr/webpack -D`

To configure this, update following in `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });

    return config;
  },
  ...
};
```

Use it as following:

```
...
import Star from './star.svg'
...
    <Star />
...
```